# Is there a field k such that $Spec(k)\times \mathbb P^1$ is affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Is there a field k such that $Spec(k)\times \mathbb P^1$ is affine?

Probably I have no technical background to claim any good idea on this. However, I think the answer should be negative since $Spec(k)=\{(0)\}$ and topologically thinking $Spec(k)\times \mathbb P^1$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ and we know that the scheme $\mathbb P^1$ is not affine.

How to correctly show this, and is my explanation so stupid?

Comment: What does $\mathbb{P}^1$ mean? Projective space over what base scheme?

Comment: I suppose by $\mathbb{P}^1$ you mean $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$, so $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \times_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}} = \mathbb{P}^1_k$ which is never affine because the global sections of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is $k$, so if it is affine, it is trivial but $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ has a lot of other points!

Answer (score 5):

Note that over an infinite field $k$, $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_k=\text{Spec } k[x]$. Being affine is not a topological property.

The best way, in my opinion, to see that the projective line is not affine is to compute the global regular functions. There are no non-constant global functions over $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ (see for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56236/do-there-exist-regular-functions-on-the-projective-space-over-a-field/62324)), so if it were affine, it would necessarily be equal to $\text{Spec } k$.